# Javascript-JQuery | How to parse HTML textarea and input values from textboxes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, xml

I am attempting to input text/variables the user has enetered into textboxes into certain words that already exist in the text area. An XML file has been pulled into the textarea so I'm wanting to modify certain keywords.

How can I do this? This is all going to be done locally. The browser pulls a file selected by user into text area, and then text fields modify this text area.

Comment: Two problems with this question: 1) You haven't provided anything close to enough details, and 2) broad "how do I do this" questions are off-topic. You need to make an attempt to solve this yourself, post your code, and then we'll help you fix it.

Comment: Just a note: There's no need to put the tags in the title; just put the title in the title section and the tags in the tags section and the right people will see it.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to complete the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read the help topic [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before posting. Good questions normally have a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Also, StackOverflow has an [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) with lots of information. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you want to change the text in the textarea based in the text in another input, so this is what i could do at glance with jquery

```
$('#input').change(function(event) {
    var newText = $('#textarea').val().replace(/textToReplace/g, $(this).val())
    $('#textarea').val(newText)
}
```

You listen to the change event in the inputs that contain the words you want to replace, and then change the textarea value after replacing that words in the current text.